# How to store INTEGER vec2 to texture using FBO and read it by glReadPixels

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, textures

I want to generate an integer texture with two channels, and I want the first channel to store the index of each vertex and the second channel to store the index of the model, so each pixel in this texture is like `(vertex_id, model_id)` and they are both integers.
Texture binding:

```cpp
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id_tex);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RG32UI, width, height, 0, GL_RG_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, id_tex, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Read pixels:

```cpp
double x, y;
glfwGetCursorPos(window, &x, &y);
unsigned rg[2];
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
glReadPixels(x, height - y - 1, 1, 1, GL_RG_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, rg);
glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);
cout << rg[0] << ' ' << rg[1] << endl;
```

shader:

```cpp
#version 450 core
layout( location = 0 ) out vec4 scene_color;
layout( location = 1 ) out vec2 vid_mid;

flat in int index;
in vec3 FragPos;
in vec3 Position;
in vec3 Normal;

uniform int mid;

void main(){
    scene_color = vec4(Normal, 1.0);
    vid_mid = vec2(index, mid);
}
```

This is [what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MRv1.png)(since the vertex index is greater than the model index, so the red color is reasonable):

But when I use `glReadPixels` to get the pixel color at `(x, y)`, [I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SWJz.png):

**But what I actually want is the `(vertex_id, model_id)`**

Answer (score 0):

If you create your texture as GL_RG32UI, you should also make sure to store it in the correct format.

```
layout( location = 1 ) out vec2 vid_mid;
```

Assumes that you output to a float format, if you want your shader to output unsigned int, it should be :

```
layout( location = 1 ) out uvec2 vid_mid;
```

and

```
vid_mid = uvec2(index, mid);
```